# Rapid Fail Protection in Azure Websites

Tags: iis, azure-web-app-service

Is Rapid Fail Protection enabled in Azure Websites?  If so, how is it configured?  I haven't been able to find any documentation on this.

Or maybe we're supposed to use the [auto-healing](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/02/06/auto-healing-windows-azure-web-sites/) functionality to handle the scenarios normally covered by Rapid Fail Protection?

Comment: Wondering the same thing. Fwiw, we have auto-healing enabled and have experienced periods of 503's with our websites that should have, but did not trigger auto-healing.

Comment: How were you able to enable auto healing?  I tried adding a monitoring section under system.webServer and couldn't even run the site locally.